# Getting text editable from loaded svg on fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to load a svg to fabric.js and be able to edit (change) the text that belongs to the svg.

However by using fabric.loadSVGFromURL() method i get a single object (of type "group") with all kind of elements, including the text.

I don't know if the following solution is the best approach but i tried to solve the question with the reviver function:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(
    url,
    function() {},
    function(svgElement, fabricObject) {
        if (fabricObject.type === "text") {
            var text = fabricObject.text;
            var optionsopt = fabricObject.toObject();
            var newEditableText = new fabric.Itext(text, optionsopt);
            canvas.add(newEditableText);
        else {
            canvas.add(fabricObject);
     }
);
```

But i'm having problems with tspan tags inside the loaded svg

Comment: Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: No we didn't @PierreOlivierTran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fabric.js SVG parser doesn't support tspan. It's still an open issue: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/1280

There may be workarounds to your problem on the above issue page, but without knowing the specific behavior of your tspans I couldn't point you to a specific workaround.